# Change an interface in typescript after an if statement

Tags: typescript

I have a simple problem, i have 1 interface User, with other interface that extends different variables like this :

```js
interface User {
  id: string;
  info: {
    businessName?: string;
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    middleNames?: string;
    phone: {
      countryCode: string;
      number: string;
    };
  };
  mail: string;
  status: string;
  role: string;
  timestamp: number;
}

interface UserNurse extends User {
  location: {
    custom: {
      lat: number;
      lng: number;
      formattedAddress: string;
      addressComponents: Array;
    };
    current: {
      lat: number;
      lng: number;
    };
    travelRadius: number; // in miles
    fromCustomLocation: bool;
  };
}
```

And in my code, i want to filter from all User a specific type of user (nurse in this case) like this :

```js
if (user.role === 'nurse') {
  const { lat, lng } = getLocationNurse(user);
  // Some logic
}
```

And my function `getLocationNurse(user: UserNurse)` is declared with the inferface UserNurse.

Is it possible after an if statement to change the interface previously defined in Typescript ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your types defined as you listed them, the compiler has no idea that `user.role === "nurse"` implies that `user` is a `UserNurse`.  The simplest way to fix that is to write a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) which expresses this idea:

```
function isNurse(user: User): user is UserNurse {
  return user.role === "nurse";
}
```

Notice how the annotated return type of `isNurse()` is the *type predicate* `user is UserNurse`.  That's a special type of `boolean` which the compiler can use to figure out if the `user` parameter is or is not a `UserNurse`.  Now you can use `isNurse(user)` instead of `user.role === "nurse"` in your check, and everything just works:

```
  if (isNurse(user)) {
    const { lat, lng } = getLocationNurse(user); // okay
    // Some logic
  }
```

---

Otherwise, if you don't want to use such a type guard function, the only way for the compiler to understand that `user.role` has any implication on the type of `user` is to make the type of `user` into a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions).  But that would require that you change your `UserNurse` definition to specify that `role` must [literally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) be `"nurse"`:

```
  interface UserNurse extends User {
    role: "nurse", // <-- add this
    location: {
      custom: {
        lat: number;
        lng: number;
        formattedAddress: string;
        addressComponents: Array<string>;
      };
      current: {
        lat: number;
        lng: number;
      };
      travelRadius: number; // in miles
      fromCustomLocation: boolean;
    };
  }
```

as well as making `user` a *union* of different subtypes of `User` with different literal values for `role`:

```
  interface UserMime extends User {
    role: "mime",
    trappedInInvisibleBox: boolean
  }

  function foo(user: UserNurse | UserMime) {
    if (user.role === "nurse") {
      const { lat, lng } = getLocationNurse(user);
      // Some logic
    }
  }
```

You can't have `user` be just `User` or `User | UserNurse`.  If you include `User`, then `user.role === "nurse"` does not eliminate the possibility that `user` might just happen to have `"nurse"` as its `role` without actually being a `UserNurse`.

Unless you have an enumerated union of different subtypes of `User`, you probably want to use the type guard function instead.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVKEBOARCAzAlsBACYAqAnjBAOICuIGxSA3gLABQSShALprgmRpMLDly75iALiRQeGQgHMA3GPGFcAexltO4rgCNaUQtCgA5cBAD8MuQuAq1+ghjmXIt2fKWq9+gBsQdysve19ncTBJYgCID2gwn0c-fS4YAAtNIh1I-XhNWmB5cgBhTWIIO2SnfzTgWjADTGqHWrSkAF9U8W7IsBB8ANaIurkQHmMRlMiMTTjp9vEefEhxsBgZBqbMHs6ONV5+QVR0DHNaN2QIAA8+YGIoU5FdQM14Cfxs3LqueGMeJowD8Olwgjwto1mhgeh0Ao5ITsYXlxFoMAMeHxiABBYjEDBmRawtIgPEEqBQcobbIQYpQGTYjAYEDkAA84UcAD5iVw+r8kP8mbSIaJ+WCJojoTzxPDFJLdii+R15CAAG4QAIAJVJ+CmSG2UqQAHojdxgEhonEoCjcHMwKUAUCADLvT7fJAGTTzCAgYDEpVdA7sINcXBFeArbJIRQQHguj6R4AXK4ACgaVxkwnOl3QAEpRfoCZMMOb0+gAHQBV2J8uCgnFPZBkNIMPACNfc34Cw5iAp4wtZ4YXMyfsYbhPLPJ9AF8RFy7m0fluZxJAAXnXSAARGWIJvG8G9K321GtJo+2dM2d8691LgkCmu1Pe6Pc9eUQVgHIWEhwQAaH+OF0a7RrG8ZukmPbnpgubSiaSAAMpAsgVaKPg8CRPseiYZhHCgGscCIEgWBdvACjRKAWIoMAHYzkcGACIRWYzhI0jeG0xIaNozHiEYJhEBSCRJOxNr4G4PCCUSKJBCEniSfy0R4nECRQEJowdJkNIgqCBRFCU5SVHJoL6lCA4cks+gBryxIDEMhniOMkz0mxamzt6dlcCsaw8OAmzGUi+6HMUxyMWcT5ILc9yPIO3HLlUW47puv6RFWCYdlp+SOsC3GBBKflSiiYIInlCpii2mjohMWK4vihLOTMpWkjVFJUjANJ0gyTIsuyNTcoq0p1sK6VpOC8rIqVsqjdKlnLMy6pajqeoGrsxqmoQFpDNANp2g6cjOtWaUel6cS+v6AV6HRDFCGcACyqzXHctJRUxN5cLFMibtEkCJZEKowFQxAAJLAEDqpdvgBhxAAQpoNwyJ63q+moOEHqG4aJiBcb7dkT5pj2l6YE+b51HOJbGVclZY8AtaXPWPBnWoR7o6eUEYPj2ZXEgAA+g63ZARP6Pgd4s0u3prhu249pu-NpB+X7MD+Ez-rKQGrhjYGJjjL6waaiGQD+mioehdSYbyHDI0AA)